# Cannot find macintosh hd in disk utility

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I did a forceful shutdown of my laptop. After that when I power on,  the laptop boots into GNU GRUB. When i check the disk utility in recovery mode, I am not able to find macintosh Hd in it. I have a time machine backup, but it cannot be restored as the drive cannot be found. Seeking your help to solve this issue.
Thanks for the support[image]

Comment: The internal storage is blank.  Re-install the OS.

Comment: @MarcWilson: You are making assumption there could very well be incorrect. The Disk Utility will show only certain items. Showing blank does not mean there is nothing there.

Comment: Thee Jinn: In recovery mode, open a Terminal window and post the output from the command `diskutil list`. Also, try to include the output from `gpt -r show /dev/disk0`. These commands will not change your Mac.